# JavaFX 2 dynamic dot loading

Tags: javafx-2

I wanna create some loading dots like this:

```
At 0 second the text on the screen is: Loading.
At 1 second the text on the screen is: Loading..
At 2 second the text on the screen is: Loading...
At 3 second the text on the screen is: Loading.
At 4 second the text on the screen is: Loading..
At 5 second the text on the screen is: Loading...
```

and so forth until I close the `Stage`.

What is the best / easiest way to make that in JavaFX? I've been looking into animations/preloaders in JavaFX but that seems to complex when trying to achieve this.

I've been trying to create a loop between these three `Text`:

```
Text dot = new Text("Loading.");
Text dotdot = new Text("Loading..");
Text dotdotdot = new Text("Loading...");
```

but the screen stays static...

How can I make this work correctly in JavaFX? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is similar to: [javafx animation looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029920/javafx-animation-looping).

Here is a solution using the JavaFX [animation framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) - it seems pretty straight forward to me and not too complex.

[image: loading animation]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/** Simple Loading Text Animation. */
public class DotLoader extends Application {
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final Label    status   = new Label("Loading");
    final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
      new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new EventHandler() {
        @Override public void handle(Event event) {
          String statusText = status.getText();
          status.setText(
            ("Loading . . .".equals(statusText))
              ? "Loading ." 
              : statusText + " ."
          );
        }
      }),  
      new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000))
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

    VBox layout = new VBox();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(status);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 50, 35));
    stage.show();

    timeline.play();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use a Progress Indicator or a Progress Bar? I think they can be a good solution to show an animation and avoid problems.

I've been able to do it in JavaFX, not with Animations, but using the concurrency classes from JavaFX.

I let you the code here [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/ajiniesta/5285742). I think it isn't very intuitive, because I prefer a progress indicator. And maybe it isn't the best solution, but maybe this will help you.

Cheers